# Using Argparse To Convert xml to csv in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, argparse

I need to accept some command line arguments like so:

```
argparse.py hi.xml --> to produce hi.csv or
argparse.py hi.xml -o hello.csv --> to produce hello.csv
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import argparse
import csv
import indent
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def get_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Converts CSV to XML")
    parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose',action='store_true',dest='verbose',help='Increases messages being printed to stdout')
    parser.add_argument("inputfile", help="Please input the name of the CSV file")
    parser.add_argument('-o','--outputfile',help='(optional) Output file name',nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ext = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[1].lower()
    if args.outputfile is None:
        if ext == ".csv":
            args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.xml'

        elif ext == ".xml":
            args.outputfile = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[0] + '.csv'

    elif args.outputfile:
        if ext == ".csv":
            outputfile = open(args.outputfile, 'w')
        elif ext == ".xml":
            outputfile = open(args.outputfile,'w')
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: Invalid extension %s\n' % ext)
        sys.exit(1)
    return args

def main(argv):
    args = get_args(argv[0:])
    if args is None:
        return 1
    ext = os.path.splitext(args.inputfile)[1].lower()
    if ext == ".csv":
        reader = read_csv(open(args.inputfile))
        generate_xml(reader, args.outputfile)

    if ext == ".xml":
        root = etree.parse(open(args.inputfile)).getroot()
        generate_csv(root, args.outputfile)


    if args.verbose:
        print ('Verbose Selected')
    if args.verbose:
        print ('Convert to XML with set name')

    return 0 

def read_csv(inputfile):
    return list(csv.reader(inputfile))

def generate_xml(reader,outfile):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)        
    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i > 0:
            x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
            if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
                current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

                collar = SubElement (current_group, 'collar',{'':', '.join((x1,y1,z1))}),
                toe = SubElement (current_group, 'toe',{'':', '.join((x2,y2,z2))})
                cost = SubElement(current_group, 'cost',{'':cost})
        i+=1
    head.set('total_holes', '%s'%i)
    indent.indent(root)
    tree.write(outfile)

def generate_csv(root, outfile):

    with open(outfile, 'w') as file_:

        writer = csv.writer(file_, delimiter="\t")

    for a in zip(root.findall("drillholes/hole/collar"),
                 root.findall("drillholes/hole/toe"),
                 root.findall("drillholes/hole/cost")):
        writer.writerow([x.text for x in a])

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

I just need help with the generate_csv part. As you can see from the function get_args(args) i obtain the parameters and this is also where i change the extension of the files using ext = .... then i return it using return args. The main function calls this function and obtains the parameters then checks for the extensions again which then leads to the next function depending on the ext. In the main function i have already parsed the xml file and so i just pass "root" and "args.outputfile" to the generate_csv method. However this is where the error occurs: xml.etree.ElementTree.parserError: no element found line 1 column 0. However, i believe that this may not be the only error and maybe the way i passed the parameters around somewhere it got lost or modified. Please help

Comment: You don't need to pass `args` to your `get_args` function.  The ArgumentParser class knows to look for the arguments from the command line.  You actually don't need to pass `sys.argv` to main either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly a minimal example, so it's hard to work out exactly what your problem is and what the specific question is.

The error says that the parser got no input. This suggests that either the file is actually empty, or the file pointer has been advanced to the end of the file. The file might be empty if you accidentally opened it for writing and truncated it to zero. The file pointer might be advanced to the end of the file if you accidentally opened it for reading, read everything from it, and neglected to rewind the file pointer.

So you can see what's going on, why not try something diagnostic that takes baby steps and prints out in between? That is, instead of `etree.parse(open(args.inputfile))`, try something like:

```
print( args.inputfile )
f = open( args.inputfile )
print( f.tell() )
print( f.read() )
f.seek(0)
xml = etree.parse( f )
print( xml )
root = xml.getroot()
print( root )
```

That way, you can see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, there was something wrong with the xml file itself but i fixed it now. Anyways, i get another error at the        writer.writerow([x.text for x in a]) line: I/O operation on a closed file

Comment: That's because the `writerow` is not inside the `with open(outfile, 'w') as file_:` construct — note the indentation level of the `for` terminates the `with` and closes the associated file.